# Oxidative cleavage of 2-methylcyclohexa-1,3-diene

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

What are the products of oxidation of 2-methylcyclohexa-1,3-diene using hot concentrated acidified $\ce{KMnO4}$ solution?

Do we approach this problem the same way we would approach oxidation of alkenes?

I'm unsure how this mechanism would work.

[image]

Comment: Yes, pretty much. After all, you have two alkenes in your starting material.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you draw out the products of oxidation of 2-methyl 1,3 cyclohexene? I'm unsure of how to start with this question.